# How to get a current webelement clientHeight and scrollHeight through javascript function?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Problem is to get clientHeight and scrollHeight of current webElement when we called a function from c# code like below,

Note: We don't have any id's in our application and accessed these webElements from xpath.

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver)?.ExecuteScript("return 
helper.getDimensions();",webElement);
```

In Javascript function,

```
var helper={
  getDimensions = function(){
     return '{webElementViewPortHeight:'+arguments[0].clientHeight}'
 }
```

}

If we pass like below statement i am getting a clientHeight for the current webElement,

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver)?.ExecuteScript("return ' 
 {webElementViewPortHeight:'+arguments[0].clientHeight}'",webElement);
```

I am expecting a value of webElement when we called a function.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant HTML of the *WebElement* would have helped us to construct a canonical answer. However you can use the following solutions:

- To retrieve the [clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight):

  ```
  Console.WriteLine((string)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].clientHeight;", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("element_id")))));
  ```
- To retrieve the [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight):

  ```
  Console.WriteLine((string)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].scrollHeight;", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("element_id")))));
  ```

---

### Java working sample

When the script is executed against the *textbox* on [Google Home Page](https://www.google.com/):

- Code Block:

  ```
  public class A_demo 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
          options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
          WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
          driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
          System.out.println("Client Height is: "+((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].clientHeight;", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("q")))).toString());
          System.out.println("Scroll Height is: "+((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].scrollHeight;", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("q")))).toString());
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Client Height is: 34
  Scroll Height is: 34
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Here a small change, Instead of calling this statement: **return arguments[0].clientHeight;** directly, Place this line of code inside a javascript function and call.